# Image size too big in Firefox works well in Chrome- Asp.net

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, .net

I am creating an e-commerce website using asp.net and have a page which dynamically displays all the products.

The only 1 issue I have-  In chrome the size of the image is correct as written in the CSS code but not sure why image width and height changes when I run the programme in FF- It becomes around 300 px each.

```
   .productImage 
{
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    vertical-align:central;
    padding:10px;
    border:10px;
    border-radius:50px;
    -moz-border-radius:50px;
    -webkit-border-radius:50px;
    display:block;
    Text-indent: -9999px;


}
```

Can someone please help me?

Comment: change **vertical-align: central;** to   **vertical-align: middle;**

Comment: Also, the CSS alone appears to be correct, so the issue must lie elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks Ross  vertical-align: middle;  works.